# Start application minimised from command prompt

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, command-line

On startup, I load a "TODO" Excel spreadsheet using the following batch command:

`start /min PATH-TO-SPREADSHEET\TODO.xls`

This works except that Excel is not minimised, only "Restored" in the middle of the screen. This has been tested on both Windows XP and 8.1 (fails on both). The `/max` parameter (to start a process maximised) does work.

I have tested this with a PDF and it works, so this may suggest a possible bug in Excel. Is there something subtlety wrong in the command that can ensure this works, regardless of the application launched?

Answer (score 4):

That isnt going to work.  `Start` is a *command prompt* command.  It It has no control over windowed applications.

However, you can still accomplish this.  Create a shortcut to your spreadsheet, say on your desktop.  Right click on that shortcut and go to "Properties" and change the "Run" field to "Minimized".    From the command prompt, you can then type `pathtofile\myshortcut.lnk` and Excel will open that spreadsheet minimized.

Comment: Hmm, I created a shortcut to TODO.xls with `Run` was set to `Minimised` When the shortcut is loaded directly...the spreadsheet is NOT minimised, but still only restored in the middle of the screen! The shortcut on Excel (no worksheet) does work, just not when a worksheet is loaded. I have now tried this on several applications and it works on some, but on others the application just ignores the `Run` setting! This looks like a bug in Excel...

Comment: I don't get it. If start can't control windowed applications, what are the /MIN and /MAX switches for?

Answer (score 1):

"todo.xls" is not an app and can't be /MAXed or /MINed

"excel.exe" is an executable app file

you should use:

start /min "PATH-TO-EXCEL_APP\excel.exe" "PATH-TO-SPREADSHEET\TODO.xls"

Answer (score -1):

start /MAX excel "PATH-TO-SPREADSHEET\TODO.xls"

then try /MIN and look at task bar.

Comment: Please Elaborate a little more on your answer to better help the person asking the question to better understand what they are doing just add some better detail.